# Close-votes how to correct the duplicate-link (if possible)?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

This is the 2nd occasion i wanted to vote to close a question and have chosen a link, but later found out there's a better fitting duplicate.

---

The last time was as follows:
I picked the duplicate link and pasted it to mark it as the "original" of the duplicate, but for some reasons I must have ticked an other link which was offered by the system, but doesn't fit at all. So i needed to retire this choice,a s nobody would agree with it.

---

So I'd like to know how could I change the link once I voted to close a Question as duplicate?

Or whether/when/how can I re-vote to close if I revised my decision?