# No answer to several posts

Tags: discussion, recent-activity

This is with respect to the apparently ceased activity on Islam SE . Questions aren't being answered( not only mine but lots of others also) . Why is it so and what can be done to reactivate the activity on Islam SE. 
JazaakAllahu khairan

Answer (score 1):

First of all, read "[Optimizing for Pearls, not Sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)". Go ahead, I'll wait.

And now onto the meat of your question: Literally *anyone* can ask a question, but it takes real skill and effort to write a question that actually *attracts* experts.

Writing answers is hard, and everyone on this site is a volunteer. If you want someone to volunteer to write good answers to people's questions, it needs to be worth their while:

- Has the questioner done any work at finding the answer themselves, or are they just expecting someone else to do all the work for them?
- Is the questioner asking something that's actually new and interesting, or are they just asking something that's already been asked a million times before?
- Has the questioner actually taken the time to ensure their question is clear, legible and contains all necessary information to actually be answerable, or have they just put in the minimum amount of effort into a one-liner?

If the questioner can't even be bothered to put effort into their own question, why should they expect anyone else to put effort into answering it? There's no such thing as a free lunch: If you want something, you need to work for it.

And what goes for questions goes for the site as a whole: What, exactly, has the community done to ensure that any experts who *do* show up actually want to stay?

- Have they voted up good questions and voted down bad questions so experts can actually *see* the interesting posts they'd want to answer?
- Have they taken the time to improve formatting and grammar on poorly-written posts?
- Have they used voting to actively encourage posts written by actual experts while actively discouraging answers written by people who don't know what they're talking about?
- Have they provided actual valuable information *to* the site that experts would actually *want* to read?

Again: Give and take. If you want experts to frequent the site, you need to put the effort into actually making this a site they *want* to frequent.

Answer (score 1):

As goldPseudo mentioned, we are volunteers here and not all of us are experts and especially not in any topic. So you can't expect us to answer easily any question for a short term. And I think this already shows that we need to take time off from our main duties to answer some questions.

I lately became tired of reading questions which are more or less the same as I've answered or seen several times again and again with a slight difference. So primarily I post a comment -giving a hint etc.- and if the Questioner is interested into more details I take my time to give a long answer. That doesn't mean that besides I do stop looking for evidences or doing research on the particular question. So IMO a comment is a first step for an answer and should show that either the question is answerable or needs to be elaborated or focused. But as to some extent discussed [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1743/close-votes-how-to-correct-the-duplicate-link-if-possible) many new users come and post a question and never reappear.

An other point is that many new questions are -with slight differences- duplicates of older ones and in a more severe moderated SE site they would have all been closed even if they are not exact duplicate (that's my experience, even if many users complain about the mod goldPseudo).

---

In the 10 months I'm active here now i rapidly found out that the activity on the site is going down more and more since at least 6-8 months and only a few questions have been really interesting or challenging. And if we declare some "homework" questions off-topic and added the duplicates maybe 1-2 of 100 questions are new, and worth answering.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, as far as I'm concerned, I am very discouraged to even participate.

The reason is the moderators. Answers get deleted with no chance of defending ones position.

When you try to mention this, then you're not heard.

Moderators intervene too strongly. On other StackExchange sites this is much less the case, and it is left to the users to vote up or down. Moderators merely intervene when absolutely necessary (and not because they don't share your opinion).

Comment: "..with no chance of defending ones position" is blatantly untrue: You obviously still have access to meta, don't you? Defending ones position on meta is exactly the right place for it, where you can present your arguments for undeletion and the community can weigh in on the value of the post (or lack thereof), or what can be done to improve it; the onus is on you to make a compelling argument in the first place. The fact that you've been unwilling or unable to do so is on you, not the moderators.

Comment: I don't agree. Surely every user plays a role and has a part in this. But in general I believe my argument still holds. The fact that there is a Meta does not change the perception I have. I tried, maybe I did not try enough in your opinion, or maybe no matter how hard I try it does not make a difference... But the perception remains.

Comment: Would you please enlighten me by giving examples of questions you have answered and your answers have been deleted. You either have an other network profile or make assumptions about how mods are on other SE sites. My personal experience shows that there's no big difference.

Comment: I cannot find it. I cannot even find my questions raised on Meta for them, but that could be because I just gave up, because no one cared. At some point I thought to simply delete my account, but at the end I just waited.

Comment: Hm... well if you remembered which questions i could take a look as i have access to moderation tools and now i could see your network profile. I don't know why it didn't work earlier!

Comment: That is really hard to say, difficult to remember. Maybe you can scan/search by my name?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm only able to check the deletions of the last 30 days directly (as i can see the queue under moderation tools). Older ones could only be found if i knew where am i supposed to search, so without any hint it's a matter of gambling or chance.